# Remove duplicate character in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, replace, duplicates, substitution

I have struggle with the following case:

In cell A1 = (a)(f)(a)(b)(a), cell A2 = (d)(a)(c)(d)(g)(d)(a)(d)

How can I get the result as follow:

Cell A1= (a)(b)(f)
Cell A2 = (a)(c)(d)(g)

I use substitute only substitute one (a) with “”.

Is there is an excel formula and vba to get the result.

Thank,
Joe

Comment: What are the rules for which duplicate gets removed?

Comment: Hi Tim , sorry for late reply.. Only one character with () exist in the cell and sort (eg. (c)(a)(c). Results is (a)(c)

Answer (score 1):

If you have `TEXTSPLIT`:

`=CONCAT("("&SORT(UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,,"(",1))))`

Comment: Thank for help. But my excel version is 2010. No unique and textsplit function

Comment: Do anyone have another solution